# how to find previous character and index for character

Tags: python

can you help me with this
so all I want is, I type text "hello" I got characters with indexes one by one in seconds

Comment: The error says you cannot perform mathematical operations on strings and integers. What do you expect something like `h - 1` to equal? Also, I suggest doing `if ch == "o"` instead of `if ch in ("o")`.

Comment: Here I want to say for some letter, if character of previous index (or in other words which is -1 from this current index in sequence of text) is equal A (in other words, contains A) do something...so with - 1 is an attempt to appeal to the previous index and ask character to compare

Comment: In your variant 2, you should place `lastElement = ch` at the end of the  loop, not just in the `else` clause.  Also, you should place test for last and current in the same `if` statement (ex. `if lastElement=='e' and elem=='l'`), just to make things clearer.  Start with that, and afterwards you can simplify conditions.

Comment: I'm trying but it does not work, cant get this index  `if lastElement == 'l' and (ch[elmt-1]) == 'e':` or maybe  `if lastElement == 'l' and text[elmt-1] == 'e':`

Answer (score 1):

For variant 2, instead of:

```
if lastElement == (ch - 1):
```

what about:

```
if lastElement == text[elmt-1]
```

Comment: @viktor80 Glad it helped. Feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: but something went wrong, I put the code above in variant2 with tour correction...

Comment: One question at a time buddy.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired output:

```
target = 'ol'
after = 'l'
before = 'e'

text = 'hello'

for elmt, ch in enumerate(text):
    print(ch, elmt)
    if ch in target:
        print('was {}'.format(ch.upper()))
    if ch == after:
        if last in before:
            print('before this {} was {}\n'.format(ch.upper(), last.upper()))
        else:
            print('before was other character not {}\n'.format(before.upper()))
    last = ch
```

Output:

```
h 0
e 1
l 2
was L
before this L was E

l 3
was L
before was other character not E

o 4
was O
```

Comment: ok in this case I can just put all ABC in target to get different combinations, but how to dived each character by second like in first one?  `print('was {}'.format(ch.upper()))` works for all characters, I want get only asked, maybe need change something?

Comment: Do you mean `if last in before` where `before = 'xyz'`?

Comment: yes exactly that's what I mean but how to do it I'm not sure

Comment: Modified my answer accordingly.